# Ktor: JsonDecodingException on valid JSON

Tags: android, kotlin, ktor, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlinx.serialization

The exception below is thrown after this code.  Interestingly it works while debugging and stepping through the code.  The exception is thrown on the last line.

Kotlin 1.3.60

Ktor 1.2.6

kotlinx.serialization 0.14.0

```
} catch (throwable: Throwable) {
   when (throwable) {
      is ClientRequestException -> {
          val statusCode = throwable.response.status.value
          val byteArray = ByteArray(throwable.response.content.availableForRead)
          throwable.response.content.readFully(byteArray, 0, byteArray.size)
          val text = String(byteArray, 0, byteArray.size, Charsets.UTF_8)
          logger.log("text is: $text")
          val isJson = throwable.response.headers["Content-Type"]?.startsWith("application/json") ?: false
          val failure = if (isJson) {
              val json = Json(JsonConfiguration.Default).parseJson(text).jsonObject
```

When not stepping through with the debugger, the log states that `text` is empty.  How can this be?  Is this running before all the content has been transferred?

```
kotlinx.serialization.json.JsonDecodingException: Invalid JSON at 0: Can't begin reading from here
 at kotlinx.serialization.json.internal.JsonReader.fail(JsonReader.kt:293)
 at kotlinx.serialization.json.internal.JsonReader.fail$default(JsonReader.kt:292)
```

Comment: try logging the `text` and make sure that the text is in JSON format

Comment: @PavanVarma updated with log results

Comment: is this code inside coroutine or suspend function?

Comment: inside a coroutine.  GlobalScope.async {...}